# Not able to Extract the ISO file using WinZip

Tags: extract, iso, winzip

ISO file which was downloaded, when I tried to extract using *WinZip 16.0 Pro(9686)- 32 bit* I got this problem.

The OS I am using is *Win XP - Professional - Version 2002- Service Pack 3*
with 4GB RAM

```
WinZip Encountered problems during this operation with file
G:\Setup\PROJECT\Lenel - OnGuard 2012\OnGuard2012\Supplimental Material Disc\Supp_Mat_Rev13. Please choose one of the following actions.
```

I pressed View Output

This was the message I got

```
Error: The system cannot find the path specified.
Cannot create G:\Setup\PROJECT\Lenel - OnGuard 2012\OnGuard2012\Supplimental Material Disc\Supp_Mat_Rev13\Credential Center Device Drivers\Card Scanning Solutions\SigniShell\SDK samples\vb.Net\SigniShell Sample\SigniShell Sample\obj\Release\SigniShell_Sample.FormCustom.resources
Severe Error:  File creation failed.
```

Please guide me to overcome this issue